# Using the Mechanize gem with the Nokogirl gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm trying to scrape a website that requires authentication to get an element on a page with an id of `#cellTotal`.

Right now, using Mechanize I have logged into the page I want to access, but using basic Nokogiri functions like:

```
@selector = page.css("#cellTotal").text
```

Gives me this error:

```
undefined method `css' for #<Mechanize::Page:0x61234f8>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get("example.com")
agent.page.forms[0]["username_field"] = "username"
agent.page.forms[0]["password_field"] = "password"
agent.page.forms[0].submit

@selector = agent.page.css("#cellTotal").text
```

How can I select an element on this page?

Comment: just use `search` instead of `css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `page.parser` to gain access to the underlying `Nokogiri` object.

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-parser

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064821/using-the-mechanize-gem-with-the-nokogirl-gem/")
agent.page.parser.class
# => Nokogiri::HTML::Document
agent.page.parser.css("#answer-23065003 .user-details a").text
# => "akatakritos"
```

Comment: when i did the same , it gave me this error ``undefined method `parser' for nil:NilClass`` . can you please give any solution to this ?

Comment: Post a new question with the relevant code. I or someone else will probably be able to figure it out for you.